# Incoming meetings not created in Calendar app

Tags: 2013, calendar, incoming-email

I am trying to create events in the SharePoint 2013 calendar app.

1. An ICS file is generated automatically with the following format (using self-written code):

   ```
   BEGIN: VCALENDAR
   PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 15.0 MIMEDIR//EN
   BEGIN:VEVENT
   LOCATION:Room ABC
   ATTENDEE;CN ="Some User":mailto: mycalendarlist@my.domain
   DESCRIPTION;ENCODING=ESCAPED-CHAR:Some body\n
   X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<html><head></head><body>Some body<br/>
   </body></html>
   SUMMARY:Some subject
   END:VEVENT
   END:VCALENDAR
   ```
2. User opens this file in Outlook 2016, chooses a meeting date and time and clicks **Send Update**
3. The email is received by the WFE server (exists in the DROP folder) and is processed by the Incoming E-Mail Timer Job (disappears) and **no** meeting/event is created in the calendar

However, if the exact same steps are repeated AND the email address for the calendar list is removed and written manually by the user in Outlook, sending the invite **does** create an event in the list.

I think that there might be some important parameter(s) missing in my auto-generated ICS that are added to the meeting by Outlook automatically when the user makes a change in the **To** field.

Any ideas/suggestions on what parameters are missing so that I could make my auto-generated ICS file work?

**Update 1**: This is because SharePoint looks for the MIME type `text/calendar` and ignores the email otherwise. In the second scenario, upon making changes in the **To** field, Outlook sends it with the proper MIME/Content type `text/calendar` and the meetings are created. There is apparently no way to influence the MIME/Content type header through the ICS.